# Create shortcut with C# on UNC path

Tags: c#, shortcut, unc

Here is my code for creating shortcuts with C#. It works only with non UNC paths, f. ex. with "C:\Users\MsX\Documents\ABC" works, but with "\\abc\klk\somepath" not works.

```
public static void CreateShortcut(string SourceFile, string ShortcutFile, string Description, string Arguments, string HotKey, string WorkingDirectory) {
      // Check necessary parameters first:
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceFile))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("SourceFile");
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ShortcutFile))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("ShortcutFile");

      // Create WshShellClass instance:
      var wshShell = new WshShellClass();

      // Create shortcut object:
      IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shorcut = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)wshShell.CreateShortcut(ShortcutFile);

      // Assign shortcut properties:
      shorcut.TargetPath = SourceFile;
      shorcut.Description = Description;
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Arguments))
        shorcut.Arguments = Arguments;
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HotKey))
        shorcut.Hotkey = HotKey;
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(WorkingDirectory))
        shorcut.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory;

      // Save the shortcut:
      shorcut.Save();
}
```

How to create shortcuts showing to network UNC folders?

Thanks

Comment: `It works only with non UNC paths` what does that mean specifically?

Comment: That meens, I can create shortcut "C:\myabc.lnk" that shows to path  "C:\Users\MsX\Documents\ABC" and I can't create shortcut that shows to (UNC) path "\\someserver\Documents\ABC".

Comment: but what happens when you click on the link with the UNC path?

Comment: I have not been able to create link ... we talking about shortcut CREATING ... and this was not successfully ... please read abowe

Comment: you **have not mentioned in your question any kind of error.** What I'm trying to figure out is **what's not happening?** Is the shortcut getting created at all? Is an error being thrown? How in the world can I help you if I have **no idea what *exactly* is and isn't happening?** And careful with your tone my friend, remember, I'm trying to help **you**.

Comment: If something not work (as I sad abowe) as expected, is that not error? I talking about shortcut creating that not work as expected (in case of using UNC paths for target). What is there not clear?